# Html Canvas - move object on X or Y axis only

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having a problem with moving an object on the canvas but only on x or y-axis once at a time.

Idea:
The user can drag an object with CTRL / Shift pressed and then he's able to move an object on the x-axis or y-axis only. I move an object on an axis that I'm further away from starting position. This feature is present in most vector software (Corel, Inkscape, etc.).

On this video you can see what I mean:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AheCfh13Aw

To be honest - I don't know where to start. I guess I have to track the origin position of the object while dragging so I can check which axis should be locked while mouse movement.

Forked jsFiddle I'm using for developing:
https://jsfiddle.net/sores/1emj47q9/38/

Mouse movement event listener:

```
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (myState.dragging) {
      console.warn('mouseMove and dragging');
      console.warn('object position: ', myState.selection);
      var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
      console.warn('mouse: ', mouse);
      // We don't want to drag the object by its top-left corner, we want to drag it
      // from where we clicked. Thats why we saved the offset and use it here

      // get the very first position of the object?
      myState.selection.x = mouse.x - myState.dragoffx;
      // y locked
      // myState.selection.y = mouse.y - myState.dragoffy;


      console.warn('new position: ', myState.selection);


      myState.valid = false; // Something's dragging so we must redraw
    }
  }, true);
```

If anyone is familiar with such a thing I will be very grateful for any tips.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is posted as **code untested**. The theory should point you in the right direction, though. I've commented the additions I've made to hopefully make it clearer but the basic rundown is;

1. Get the current mouse position
2. Move the mouse
3. Get the new mouse position
4. Compare the new mouse position against the old one
5. The biggest difference in positions determines the axis

When you've determined the direction (such as y), reset the position of the other axis (in this case, x) as it'll probably move slightly. I haven't included code for this.

```js
// A reference to the previous mouse position
let initialMousePosition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}
// A reference to locked axis that can be set or unset later
let dragLock: {
  x: false,
  y: false
}
// A reference to the control key
let ctrlPressed = false;

// Moved previousMousePosition logic in to on mouse down for increased reliability
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
  
    initialMousePosition.x = mouse.x;
    initialMousePosition.y = mouse.y;
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (myState.dragging) {
    var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);

    // check for 0 positions to skip the first tick
    if (initialMousePosition.x > 0 || initialMousePosition.y > 0) {
      // compare previous mouse x & y positions to the current mouse positions
      // assume the biggest difference is the direction of dragging
      if (mouse.x - initialMousePosition.x > mouse.y - initialMousePosition.y) {
        dragLock.y = true;
      } else {
        dragLock.x = true;
      }
    }

    if (!dragLock.x || !ctrlPressed) myState.selection.x = mouse.x - myState.dragoffx;
    if (!dragLock.y || !ctrlPressed) myState.selection.y = mouse.y - myState.dragoffy;

    myState.valid = false; // Something's dragging so we must redraw
  }
}, true);

//
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (event.which == "17")
    ctrlPressed = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  ctrlPressed = false;
})
```

Comment: I will check that, but I guess the problem is with the mouse position. I can't compare current mouse pos with the previous as it's being overwrite with every fired mousemove event. I think I have to compare current mouse pos with positiong where I started dragging. Does that make sense or am I making things up right now? Sketch: https://ibb.co/80jRLhH

Comment: Either way should work just fine - that's why I don't assign `previousMousePosition` until the end of the function . The way I see it is you basically need to decide which direction you're going as quickly as possible - and this won't change until the mouse is released. Setting `previousMousePosition` in the `onmousedown` canvas event would probably be more reliable, as you say, as that way it's only set once. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That's the tricky part as it can change during mousemove event. Let's say you go right for 100 px, the y-axis is locked, but then you move mouse up 200 px (without releasing mouse) so now the x-axis should be locked.

Comment: @beribazoo Yep, good shout. I've updated the answer. The `initialMousePosition` will not change now during dragging. Setting it on mouseDown ensures it is only set once.

Comment: I'm on it. We will see how it's gonna work. Thanks!